# I cannot update state with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

In this edit class I fetch data from the server successfully and I used `getDerivedStateFromProps` to set the state initial values but when I try to edit any data nothing changed, `formdata` does not change. Why is that and what I should do to fix it?

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {getBook, updateBook, clearBook, deleteBook} from '../../actions'

class EditBook extends PureComponent {

    state = {
        formdata: {
            _id: this.props.match.params.id,
            name: '',
            author: '',
            review: '',
            pages: '',
            rating: 1,
            price: ''
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.dispatch(getBook(this.props.match.params.id));
    }

    handleInput = (e, name) => {
        let newFormdata = {...this.state.formdata}
        newFormdata[name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({formdata: newFormdata});
    }

    submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.dispatch(updateBook(this.state.formdata));
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {

        let book = nextProps.book_reducer.book || '';
        return {
            formdata: {
                name: book.name,
                author: book.author,
                review: book.review,
                pages: book.pages,
                rating: book.rating,
                price: book.price
            }
        }

    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div className="rl_container article">
                <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                    <h2>Edit review</h2>
                    <div className="form_element">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" value={this.state.formdata.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'name')} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form_element">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Author" value={this.state.formdata.author} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'author')} />
                    </div>
                    <textarea value={this.state.formdata.review} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'review')} />
                    <div className="form_element">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Pages" value={this.state.formdata.pages} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'pages')} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form_element">
                        <select value={this.state.formdata.rating} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'rating')}>
                            <option val="1">1</option>
                            <option val="2">2</option>
                            <option val="3">3</option>
                            <option val="4">4</option>
                            <option val="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form_element">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Price" value={this.state.formdata.price} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'price')}/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Update Review</button>
                    <div className="delete_post">
                        <div className="button">Delete Review</div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        book_reducer: state.book_reducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditBook)
```

Comment: Is this reactjs or nextjs? And can you let me know which version you are using?

Comment: reactjs 16.13.1

Comment: your current code is wrong. so once you change any input, it will change state using handeInput. and once state changes, getDerivedStateFromProps will be called and it will initialize the state again. If you want to initialize once in this component like componentDidMount, you can add condition.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops
Read this and know when this function is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` function is fired every time before rendering.

Check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

For your solution, you have to wrap it with a condition.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {

    let book = nextProps.book_reducer.book || '';
    if (!prevState.formdata.name) {
      return {
            formdata: {
                name: book.name,
                author: book.author,
                review: book.review,
                pages: book.pages,
                rating: book.rating,
                price: book.price
            }
        }

    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: changed to this `if (!prevState.formdata.name) {`